# How to apply VLOOKUP function for partial match in a sentence or directory path?

Tags: excel, search, conditional-statements

I have two sheets. Sheet 2 contains bunch of keywords or the actual values. Sheet 1 contains some very long strings. Among the long strings, I need to find if there is match from the keyword on other page. Whenever there is a match from the set of keyword, it will display Yes, or no (Displaying the specific keyword would be very helpful to identify easily). My sheet looks like this:

Sheet 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gqK3.png)

Sheet 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBXFU.png)

If anyone can help me how to implement this condition or search function in excel, that would be very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Array formula (unless you're on 365):

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$17,A2)),"Yes","No")
```

should do it.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to reference the value that has a match?

Comment: @RingtailLemur Could there be more than one match? If so, what should the result be?

Comment: There won't be more than one match.

Comment: @RingtailLemur which version of Excel?